# Unable to add iOS dependency to Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-plugin

I am creating a Flutter plugin. But when I am trying to add a dependency to iOS part of the plugin I am not finding any proper guideline for this. I declared the dependency in the `podspec` file of my plugin. But the dependency is only available in the `example/ios` through Pod but I want access that dependency in my `ios` folder of my plugin. This is my `podspec`:

```
#
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'comet_chat'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new Flutter plugin.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter plugin.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'CometChatPro', '1.4.0'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
  s.preserve_paths = 'CometChatPro.framework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework CometChatPro' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'CometChatPro.framework'
end
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17978#) issue but it was of no help. How to solve this issue? How can I get my dependency only for the plugin?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Are you add to infoplist ?

Comment: Have you add this dependency to ios folder or the example/ios folder?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes ios doesn't fetch dependencies from the flutter, in that condition I use this method to get sync dependencies.
first you need to run the clean

`flutter clean`

then you need to delete Podfile.lock

`rm Podfile.lock`

and delete Pods folder as well

`rm -rf Pods/`

then install Pod

`pod install`

And your all dependencies will be synced.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "only open the plugin's classes", and the dependencies you add in your `podspec` are only available to your plugin, unless explicitly made it public.

*TL;DR*

By design, your iOS Flutter plugin will always run when embedded in a Flutter application project. Also, there is a conflict in your `podspec`; **it should never specify *the same framework* in both `dependency` and `vendored_frameworks`**.

If you have a `CometChatPro.framework` folder, copy it in your plugin's `ios/Libraries` folder and declare its path in your `podspec` in `vendored_frameworks`. Personally, I've never used the `dependency` specifier but there is an example in the **[`flutter-webrtc` plugin's implementation](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/main/ios/flutter_webrtc.podspec)**.

Either way, the `ios/Classes` folder of your plugin **does have access** to the dependencies that you specify in your `ios/plugin_name.podpsec` file. It just doesn't "know it" when you edit your plugin in any editor other than Xcode (Visual Studio Code, Android Studio, etc).

To develop the Swift or Objective-C classes for your plugin's iOS implementation, you should :

1. Open the example's Xcode workspace located at `example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace`.
2. Edit your **plugin**'s iOS classes by navigating in Xcode to `Pods/Development Pods/plugin_name/../../ios/.symlinks/plugins/plugin_name/ios/Classes`
3. Build your project to fix any compiling errors.

*If at this point you still don't have access to the framework in your plugin's iOS classes, it means that it wasn't properly setup by Cocoapods. In that case, you'll need to find which Xcode Build Setting is not properly set and then specify these Build Settings in your plugin's `podspec`, like so:*

```
  s.xcconfig = { 
                'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => ['${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/Libraries'],
                'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => ["${PODS_ROOT}/../.symlinks/plugins/plugin_name/ios/Libraries/CometChatPro.framework/Headers"
               }
```

*This explicitly adds the framework to your plugin target's `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, and the framework's `Headers` path to the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATH`.*

When linking `vendored_frameworks`, you want to make sure that Cocoapods did successfully embed the framework, and that you are building for the right architectures.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- In your Flutter plugin open `.podspec` file and add the required
  dependency as show below.

**For your reference**

- In my flutter plugin, I have added `AzureCommunicationCommon, AzureCommunicationChat`
  package with the required version
- Also make sure to take care of `s.pod_target_xcconfig`

Comment: What should we do in `s.pod_target_xcconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your file in the ios/ folder of the plugin to solve the problem:

```
  s.preserve_paths = 'yourframework.framework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework yourframework' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'yourframework.framework'
```

then run `pod update`